# what would make this if decision carry out what's in the braces?

Tags: php

I have tried everything to try understand what the `if` part of this statement truly accomplishes. It appears that no value that can be assigned to $_var will actually make the `if` statement carryout what's inside the braces. Can someone help me to understand why someone would use this `if` syntax in production code?

```
<?php
$_var=true;
if(!$_var =func() ) {echo 'returning false';//never prints!?

                }

echo $_var;
function func(){ echo 'test';return 3;}     
?>
```

Comment: I am at work and therefore cannot test this out, but what happens if you `return false` inside of `func()`?

Comment: why is = and not == , its always true the assignment

Comment: you probably want `$var != func()` not `!$var = func()`

Comment: @sterefrog, Haim... Thanks for your input, this is a snippet of code which comes from a larger script which I am studying, so I am trying to figure out why it is the way it is, not to change it.

Comment: @Anthony, Thanks you were on the right track. It is solely predicated on what func() returns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMHO this is what happens:

func() will always return 3. Then 3 is assigned to $_var. Finally the expression !3 is evaluated, which is always false (only !0 is true), and therefore it will never print "returning false"

In fact if you return 0 from func(), it will print "returning false".

Of course, the most obvious thing is to check whether the = was in fact meant to be ==.

Comment: I wanted to write exactly the same answer, but when I tried to do so, a page telling me "StackOverflow.com is currently offline for maintenance" has appeared. Grr. And when I've realized that it works again, I saw your answer... I was angry. :P Anyway, +1.

Comment: I saw the offline for maintenance too, but then after refreshing it came back... sorry about that :)

Comment: It's not your fault, don't feel sorry :P "First come first served" they say.

Comment: your answer has proven to be correct, Thank you. If you had to word this statement out, how would you word it? like this maybe? if func() returns true to _var, then if evaluates to false?

Comment: @cube: It's as simple as this: "$_var = func(); if(!$_var) { echo 'returning false'; }"